# Load static imagse with dynamic path in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

For some reason, the image is not getting loaded this way instead I see a dark gray background.

```
{[...Array(5)].map((i, index)=>
  <Image source={{uri: `../assets/${index}.jpg`}}>
}
```

I also tried to load using the `require` method but it threw a syntax error because dynamic imports were not valid.

```
{[...Array(5)].map((i, index)=>
  <Image source={require(`../assets/${index}.jpg`)}>
}
```

But what did work was:

```
{[...Array(5)].map((i, index)=>
  <Image source={require('../assets/1.jpg')}>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React compiler need to require your images before during build by analyzing your code statically. You could do so:

```
const images = [require('../assets/1.jpg'), require('../assets/2.jpg'), require('../assets/4.jpg')];
```

```
{images.map((url)=>
  <Image source={`${url}`}>
}
```

Otherwise, you need to put them on a server and get them at runtime, like so:

```
{[...Array(5)].map((i, index)=>
  <Image source={{uri: `https://server.com/assets${i}.jpg`}}>
}
```